# What is "Shell as organizational sandbox"?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In the Mobile OS feature mapping for IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation and IBM [Worklight products](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039422)
 MFPF provides "Shell as organizational sandbox" feature. But what does "Shell as organizational sandbox" mean?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The main idea behind the shell component methodology is to create two levels of development inside the organization:

Developers who are skilled in native development implement native and web code-bases that can be used as a starting point for one or more applications. For example:

- Native functionality to be invoked from JavaScript (Cordova plug-ins)
- Authentication framework
- Security configuration
- Web resources that are shared between applications, such as logotypes and themes

Developers who have fewer skills in native development but more web expertise receive a ready-to-use shell component and use it as a wrapper to create the organization applications. For example:

- Business logic
- UI development
- Data integration

Read more about the Shell feature: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/6.3/advanced-topics/shell-development-concepts/

> Note: the Shell feature is discontinued starting MobileFirst Foundation 8.0